# How should i unjailbreak Unc0ver jailbroken iphone without rootfs backup?

Tags: iphone

so i have an problem i want to remove jailbreak from mine iphone 6s it has IOS 15.3, would restoring the ipsw restore the rootfs too??
I have tried to restore the iphone from settings but it didnt unjailbreak.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unjailbreaking your device is usually done by restoring an APFS Snapshot made by the jailbreak tool before jailbreaking the device.

Normal jailbreak procedure requires the tool to drop a binary pack and a bootstrap onto the file system. This includes the tweak injector binary and libraries (Substitute, Substrate, LibHooker, etc), and the support binaries (standard Unix tools, etc.).

These would normally only be injected into the File System once, then re-jailbreaking after reboot just runs the exploit and the in-memory patches.

Restoring the APFS Snapshot to the clean one is done directly from the jailbreak tool.

For Unc0ver jailbreak, in Unc0ver's Settings page there's a toggle called "Restore ROOT FS". Once you toggle that on, and go back to the main jailbreak screen, the big blue button changes from "Jailbreak" to "Restore ROOT FS". Press it, wait for the reboot and once the device has rebooted, you're now stock iOS with no trace of the jailbreak left.

For Odyssey and Taurine Jailbreak is the same thing. The ROOT FS restore toggle is in Settings.

For CheckRa1n Jailbreak, there is no toggle. While being jailbroken, open the CheckRa1n app on your iOS device and press "Restore System". It's the red button at the bottom.

After the reboot, there will be no trace left of the jailbreak.

Erasing all contents from Settings may NOT remove the jailbreak files from the FS completely.